# QGIS3 error Python on launch, Ubuntu 16.4

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, python-3, pyqt5

I installed QGIS3 on ubuntu 16.4.

When I launch QGIS I get an error:

```
Impossible de charger PyQt. (Can't load PyQt)
Le support Python va être désactivé. (Python support will be deactivate)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.9' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.so)


Version de Python :
3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Version de QGIS :
3.0.0-Girona 'Girona', 0def61c

Chemin vers Python : (Path to Python)
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/sangis/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles
/default/python', '/home/sangis/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default
/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/lib
/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-
linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/sangis/.local
/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I can continue to use QGIS but I can't access the classic plugins list in the plugin menu (only 8 plugins available).

I tried to fix it by installing Qt5.9.

any idea how I can fix this error?

Comment: libqt5core5a version 5.9 is only available for artful and bionic, not for xenial. You might have installed wrong packages. BTW I wonder where you got python 3.5.2 from, the main ubuntu repo still has 3.5.1-3.

Comment: @SanGis I am with the same problem. Have you found any solution?

Comment: @DiogoCaribé if you have updated QT5 with pip, you have to revert that to the xenial package. Otherwise QGIS won't run.